# top menu bar creation

Tags: c#, menubar

What I want to do is simply have a menu bar at the top of my game. The ones that have File, Edit, Help, Etc. If anyone knows how to do that, that would be great!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms?

Comment: I am not sure what Windows Forms are, so no.

Comment: You can do it! Winforms and WPF are relatively easy, straight up XNA you'll have to roll your own. This is way too broad though, especially without knowing your display tech. Please narrow the question and show what you have tried/looked at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built in control.

You can make one like this:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_Open"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Close"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Save"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Edit">
        <MenuItem Header="_Help">
    </Menu>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: I am not sure how to do that in XNA. Is there another file or soemthing?

Comment: The code that I have posted is XAML markup which must be placed in a .xaml file. Here is a good tutorial for using XAML with XNA: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/iersoy/using-xaml-user-controls-in-xna/

Comment: Great! This looks like it will work. Thanks for your help!